# React delay component unmount until the next component is ready to render

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am sorry if the title of my question does not make sense or the whole question :)

How to achieve this behaviour in npmjs.com when navigating in React's different components? go to npmjs.com, search for react, click on next page, the current page does not unmount, instead they show a progress bar and wait for the next page to get ready and then show it.

Is it possible to implement this in navigating between different components using react-router-dom?

Thanks

Comment: Code Splitting and lazy load might help

Comment: https://itnext.io/react-router-transitions-with-lazy-loading-2faa7a1d24a